# Customizing deploy key and ssh wrapper path for git cloning through application_git cookbook

Tags: git, deployment, chef

I am using Chef 12.0.3 for managing servers. Earlier I was using application cookbook for cloning repository. But now in higher version of application cookbook, this support is moved to new cookbook application_git.

Issue:

1. I want to change the path of deploy key
2. Contents of ssh_wrapper
3. Path of ssh_wrapper.

What I have tried (Current code):

```
application 'accounts' do
  action :deploy
  path <somepath>
  owner 'nobody'
  group 'nogroup'
  git 'name' do
    repository <repopath>
    revision <value>
    deploy_key deploy_key
 end
end
```

I am not able to find if I need to pass path using ssh_wrapper_path or ssh_wrapper or deploy_key_path. All are failing.

Currently, I am able to get keys and wrapper but at a wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the cookbook [README](https://github.com/poise/application_git/blob/master/README.md#properties):

> deploy_key – SSH key to use with git. Can be specified either as a
>   path to key file already created or as a string value containing the
>   key directly.

And:

> The application_git resource deploys code from git. It extends the
>   core git resource to support deploy keys and disabling strict host key
>   verification.

So checking the core git resource [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html#properties):

> ssh_wrapper Ruby Type: String
>
> The path to the wrapper script used when running SSH with git. The
>   GIT_SSH environment variable is set to this.

so something like this (untested) should do (using the wrapper in the cookbook) :

```
cookbook_file '/path/to/my/desired/ssh_wrapper.sh' do
  source 'my_ssh_wrapper.sh'
end

application 'accounts' do
  action :deploy
  path <somepath>
  owner 'nobody'
  group 'nogroup'
  git 'name' do
    repository <repopath>
    revision <value>
    ssh_wrapper '/path/to/my/desired/ssh_wrapper.sh'
    deploy_key deploy_key
 end
end
```

You can of course do the same with the deploy_key, but using something like chef_vault or an encrypted databag sounds better to avoid commiting deploy keys within the cookbook.

Comment: Ssh_wrapper change will work with this. But main issue is for deploy_key path

Comment: What is the problem using another cookbook_file resource for deploy_key ?